# ChatGPT Assistant Knowledge File Upload JSON Structure

Tags: python-3.x, openai-api, chatgpt-api

i am trying to upload a json file with a article structure. So that GPT Assistant can access the JSON File via File Upload. I tried give a .json, .txt and .pdf file.

But i always get the error:

```
openai.BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': "Invalid file format. Supported formats: ['c', 'cpp', 'csv', 'docx', 'html', 'java', 'json', 'md', 'pdf', 'php', 'pptx', 'py', 'rb', 'tex', 'txt', 'css', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'js', 'gif', 'png', 'tar', 'ts', 'xlsx', 'xml', 'zip']", 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': None, 'code': None}}
```

This is the Article Structure i try to upload

```
{
"article": {
"title": "",
"introduction": "",
"paragraphs": [
{
"paragraphTitle": "",
"subParagraphs": [
{
"subParagraphTitle": "",
"subParagraphPoints": ["", ""]
},
{
"subParagraphTitle": "",
"subParagraphPoints": ["", ""]
}
]
},
{
"paragraphTitle": "",
"subParagraphs": [
{
"subParagraphTitle": "",
"subParagraphPoints": ["", ""]
},
{
"subParagraphTitle": "",
"subParagraphPoints": ["", ""]
}
]
}
],
"conclusion": ""
}
  }
```

This is my Code

```
def upload_file(path):
    
    file = client.files.create(
        file=open(path, "rb"), purpose="assistants" 
        
    )
    return file

file_path = testfiles\article_structure.txt

file = upload_file(path=file_path)
```

One further strange behavior:

If i change the content of my .txt file to a simple string e.g. "Hello World" the file is accepted. But when i put the json article structure in it. I get the error mentioned above again.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us your code.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to put JSON in a `.txt` file?

Comment: Yes, because first i put it standard in .json. This didn't work, then i tried to put the strucutre in a simple txt file. Because i thought maybe this whole assistant feature is still beta and has some problems. So i wanted to pass it in a simpler format .txt. But nothing works.

Comment: This needs to be `.json`. What error did you get when you tried `.json`?

Comment: I get the same error. I get the error in .json and .txt. If i change the content of the file to a simple string "Hello World" , the file is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Guys,

i found the problem.

As you can see in my JSON Structure, i have empty Values ("") as placeholder.
But this is exactly what seems to cause the problem.

If i add Values, the file is accepted.

```
{
    "article": {
      "title": "This is a title",
      "introduction": "",
      "paragraphs": [
        {
          "paragraphTitle": "This is prargraph title 1",
          "subParagraphs": [
            {
              "subParagraphTitle": "This is subprargraph title 1.1",
              "subParagraphPoints": [
                "",
                ""
              ]
            },
            {
              "subParagraphTitle": "This is subprargraph title 1.2",
              "subParagraphPoints": [
                "",
                ""
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "paragraphTitle": "This is prargraph title 2",
          "subParagraphs": [
            {
              "subParagraphTitle": "This is subprargraph title 2.1",
              "subParagraphPoints": [
                "",
                ""
              ]
            },
            {
              "subParagraphTitle": "This is subprargraph title 2.2",
              "subParagraphPoints": [
                "",
                ""
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "conclusion": ""
    }
  }
```